# Is there a way to add more tags to the tag cloud?

Tags: widgets, tags

I have over 100 tags on my blog, but in the tag cloud there's less that 50. I don't really care about that, but I want to align the widgets in the blog footer, so I need to add 10 or 20 more tags to the cloud. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tag cloud widget uses `wp_tag_cloud()` to display the tags, which defaults to 45 tags.

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_tag_cloud/

One can use the `widget_tag_cloud_args` filter to change this number (and any other arguments passed to `wp_tag_cloud()`. Here's an example:

```
function wpse_235908_tag_cloud_args( $args ) {
    $args['number'] = 70; // the number of tags you want to display.
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'wpse_235908_tag_cloud_args' );
```

You can add this piece of code in a custom plugin or your theme's function.php file for example.

Note: There's also a [doc reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_tag_cloud_args/) for the `widget_tag_cloud_args` filter, but the documentation is currently wrong as per [this core ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37654).

Answer (score 0):

To increase the number of tags displayed by the Tag Cloud widget, you can add in functions.php the code below (testing in WordPress 6.1.1)

```
function render_block_data_aleksvgrig($parsed_block) {
    if (isset($parsed_block['blockName']) && $parsed_block['blockName'] === 'core/tag-cloud') {
        //Let's change the number of displayed tags.
        //If you do not change the limit on the maximum number of tags, then the value will be automatically reset to the default value (45)
        //in method WP_Block_Type::prepare_attributes_for_render
        $parsed_block['attrs']['numberOfTags'] = 1000;
    }
    return $parsed_block;
}

function block_type_metadata_aleksvgrig($metadata) {
    if (isset($metadata['name']) && $metadata['name'] === 'core/tag-cloud') {
        //Change the limit on the maximum number of tags (default 100)
        //For validation in method WP_Block_Type::prepare_attributes_for_render
        $metadata['attributes']['numberOfTags']['maximum'] = 1000;
    }
    return $metadata;
}

add_filter('render_block_data', 'render_block_data_aleksvgrig');
add_filter('block_type_metadata', 'block_type_metadata_aleksvgrig');
```